# No Such Module 'Parse'

Tags: swift, parse-platform, xcode6

I am copying the parse frameworks to my `Xcode` project and checking the checkbox that says Copy files if needed.

Projects runs without a problem. But when if I move the `Parse SDK` folder to the trash `Xcode` says "No Such Module 'Parse'".

It should not say that because I am copying files not making file references to my project. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 12):

I just had this problem, and I got it to work by doing this:

I opened my `Target > Build Settings > Search Paths > Framework Search Paths`.

[image]

I added two values: `$(PROJECT_DIR)` and `$(inherited)`

I don't know why these were empty in the first place, but there you have it.

Answer (score 10):

I was having the same issue.

In my case, using swift and CocoaPods, I didn't have to `import Parse` in my AppDelegate. I only needed to `#import <Parse/Parse.h> #import <Bolts/BFTask.h>` on my Bridging header.

Comment: This was it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Note Parse is written in ObjC so if you are writing a parse only app you will need to add a bridging header

Answer (score 10):

The issue for me was related to removing the comments in the podfile necessary for Swift to work. Check it out here.

"Replace the two commented lines with the following:

platform :ios, "8.0"

use_frameworks!

This tells CocoaPods that your project is targeting iOS 8.0 and will be using frameworks instead of static libraries."

http://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift

Comment: The parse quick start documentation isn't very thorough...for the cocoapods part they assume you're already using frameworks. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, clean the project. Then delete all the Parse SDKs you have. Then add the sdks to the project and also move the actual framework to the Projects folder.

Hope that helps,

Julian

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but only one view controller was telling me there was no PARSE.  I fixed it by copying everything below the import Parse statement, then adding a new view controller with the same name.  Then I just pasted my code back in.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation I had to keep on removing and then adding it every single build. The problem was that I had a space in my project file (NEVER DO THIS it creates so many problems). For example you name your app "Example App". This will make all the folders have spaces in them. So instead of having one row in Frameworks search paths your will have 2 since xcode will create another row when it sees the space. They will be `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Example` and `App/parse-library-X.X.X` due to an error in xcode. To fix this problem replace these 2 rows with one that reads `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Example\ App/parse-library-X.X.X`. Note the forward slash makes xcode read it as one file address with a space in it. This is also how you refer to folders/files in finder that have spaces in them.

Answer (score 1):

### Differences in ios versions are causing problems

AppDelegate has methods that can be used depending on the ios version, and methods that cannot be used.
If they are present, xcode will not load the library.
So adding the following to the top of each AppDelegate function for solves the problem.
In Swift, you use the `@available attribute` to control whether a declaration is available to use when building an app for a particular target platform.
in my case add

```swift
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
```

### import Parse become no error.

[image]