# No such module 'Parse' error even after installing the frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am getting the error 'No such module Parse' even though I have added all of the needed frameworks.  I get this error when I try to import Parse at the top of my appdelegate or my viewcontroller.

Here is a screen shot:[image]

I want wasnt able to use the downloadable pro from parse because it was outdated.  My goal is to get rid of this error. Please describe your answer because I know that this answer can be complicated do I have to do something in my search paths? Once again here is my error: 'No such module Parse'. Thanks for the help I appreciate it very much you can also download the project at this link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wn7wamqdp4ty34h/AADxXGMByvvaUYfzsBZ2Ej1Oa?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Try to import it in the `Bridging-Header.h` like:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>
```

### Create Briding-Header.h

[Create a new Objective-C File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFRB5.png)

[Choose Create Bridging Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2b9m.png)

You can also try this: [terhechtes answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31077255/5762417) or [B Ks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32681292/5762417)

Comment: Now I get this error 'Parse/Parse.h' file not found

Comment: @MazzaMan Press 'shift+command+k' to clean your project and then build it again

Answer (score 0):

How did you import your Parse framework? Manually or through Cocoapods(recommended)? @JulianPomper's advice is correct so long as everything is set up properly, but you don't need to import Bolts.

Comment: Could you put the fixed project on dropbox

Comment: @MazzaMan not here to do your work for you, just to provide advice.  Check your project's Build Phases to ensure that the Parse and Bolts library are linked.  If they are and you are still having issues, I would recommend using Cocoapods to install Parse.  I have done this with several projects and have encountered no issues.