# pod in testing target return no such module error

Tags: cocoapods, cocoapods-1.2

I have the following pod file, which works fine for my normal code but as soon as I want to import a pod from the test target in one of my tests it says No such module. I have tried building for testing, building for normal, I literally tried everything that came up in my mind without luck. What am I doing wrong here?

```
target 'MyApp' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'RxSwift'

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    pod 'RxTest'
    pod 'RxBlocking'
  end
end
```

I use CocoaPods 1.2.1

Comment: How did you resolve this issue?  I might be seeing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663180/no-such-module-parse) post helpful. By making sure I had the same path values and user defined variables in both targets, I was able to get passed this error.