# Swift No such module Parse

Tags: swift, xcode, viewcontroller, parse-server

It appears always the message: No such module Parse. But only in the ViewController. I did already new now this. The problem is unfortunately still. can someone continue help please. I can't go further. Thank you very much

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663180/no-such-module-parse

Comment: Thank you. I already realized that and the articeles did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do these things :-

1. Deep Clean your project than build.[shift+option+cmd+k]
2. Remove your dependency from pod file and reinstall it. Add Parse to your bridging header than build your project.

May be it will work.

Comment: Many Thanks. How do I do this? : Remove your dependency from pod file and reinstall it. Add Parse to your bridging header than build your project.

Comment: Did you use Cocoapods to install your dependency?

Comment: Yes exactly. First Cocoadods after Parse

Comment: Do you have pod file to install parse?

Comment: Yes I had adapted the pod file and then installed it. Everything worked. It started when the app crashed while logging in. In the terminal I received the error message: Unable to find framework using path: /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoSubscriberAccount.framework

Comment: Ok. Did you removed and reinstall the parse? Can you show your console error?

Comment: No, I did not reinstall it. Can I just reinstall this? or how do I go there best?
I can not post the console error until the evening. Did not have my MAC

Comment: VideoSubscriberAccount.framework what is this? Is this your custom framework?

Comment: I dont know. This is my first app. I have just installed the two things

Comment: Don't worry, it will solve. When you will have mac than send screenshot of error. It will help to debug and find the actual problem.

Comment: That's very nice, thank you very much. As soon as I'm at home I send the sccrenshot

Comment: Start a new message by no. not more :-) find module parse. At the application or registration in the app, the app crashes always have ap. Here the console output: