# Parse module not found

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I keep getting that error every time even tho I installed the pod the right way, i'm pretty sure that its a problem of Xcode and there's something that u need to set up to make it work, i would really love to get some help with that due to the fact that I spent the whole day on it :\
I know there are tons of questions about that topic but to be honest none solved my problem :(

here's the warnning line:

> ELRatingPopupViewController.swift:11:8: No such module 'Parse'

Comment: Did you initialised the SDK as described here? https://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/

Comment: @ZsoltBiró yep :\

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No Such Module 'Parse'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663180/no-such-module-parse)

Comment: @ZsoltBiró No :\ I saw that post